# How to group in R with partial match and assign a column with the aggregated value?

Tags: r, aggregate

Below is the data frame I have:

```
   Quarter   Revenue  
1   2014-Q1     10
2   2014-Q2     20
3   2014-Q3     30
4   2014-Q4     40
5   2015-Q1     50
6   2015-Q2     60
7   2015-Q3     70
8   2015-Q4     80
```

I want to find the mean of the quarters containing Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 separately (for e.g. for text containing Q1, I have two values for revenue i.e. 10 and 50, the mean of which is 30) and insert a column depicting the mean. The o/p should look like the one described below:

```
   Quarter   Revenue  Aggregate
1   2014-Q1     10       30
2   2014-Q2     20       40
3   2014-Q3     30       50
4   2014-Q4     40       60
5   2015-Q1     50       30
6   2015-Q2     60       40
7   2015-Q3     70       50
8   2015-Q4     80       60
```

Could you all please let me know if there are any processes without using the popular packages and with using too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `separate` the "Quarter" into "Year", "Quart", group by "Quart", and get the `mean` of "Revenue"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Quarter, into = c("Year", "Quart"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
        group_by(Quart) %>%
        mutate(Aggregate = mean(Revenue)) %>%
        ungroup() %>% 
        select(-Quart, -Year)
#  Quarter Revenue Aggregate
#    <chr>   <int>     <dbl>
#1 2014-Q1      10        30
#2 2014-Q2      20        40
#3 2014-Q3      30        50
#4 2014-Q4      40        60
#5 2015-Q1      50        30
#6 2015-Q2      60        40
#7 2015-Q3      70        50
#8 2015-Q4      80        60
```

---

Or we can do this compactly with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by the substring of 'Quarter (removed the Year and `-`), we assign (`:=`) the `mean` of 'Revenue' to create the 'Aggregate'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Aggregate := mean(Revenue) ,.(sub(".*-", "", Quarter))]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using functions from the base package.

```
qtr <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
avg <- numeric()

for (n in 1:length(qtr)) {
  ind <- grep(qtr[n], df1$Quarter)
  avg[length(avg) + 1] <- mean(df1$Revenue[ind])
}

df1 <- transform(df1, Aggregate = avg)
```

Apparently using functions from other packages (e.g., dplyr) make code less verbose.